# Derive qsv hwdevice from D3D11VA hwdevice using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

I'm trying to derive a QSV hwcontext from D3D11VA device in order to encode d3d11 frames but I'm getting an error when calling av_hwdevice_ctx_create_derived.

```
  buffer_t ctx_buf { av_hwdevice_ctx_alloc(AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_D3D11VA) };

  auto ctx = (AVD3D11VADeviceContext *)((AVHWDeviceContext *)ctx_buf->data)->hwctx;

  std::fill_n((std::uint8_t *)ctx, sizeof(AVD3D11VADeviceContext), 0);

  auto device = (ID3D11Device *)hwdevice_ctx->data;

  device->AddRef();
  ctx->device = device;

  ctx->lock_ctx = (void *)1;
  ctx->lock     = do_nothing;
  ctx->unlock   = do_nothing;

  auto err = av_hwdevice_ctx_init(ctx_buf.get());
```

and then I call

```
  av_hwdevice_ctx_create_derived(&derive_hw_device_ctx, AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_QSV, ctx_buf.get(), 0);
```

I'm seeing this in the log:

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 000001de119a9b80] Initialize MFX session: API version is 1.35, implementation version is 1.30
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 000001de119a9b80] Error setting child device handle: -16
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how to fix it or a different approach to encode d3d11 frames on QSV encoder.

Thank you.

```
OS: windows 10 64bits
CPU: Intel i5-8400
Graphics card: Nvidia GT1030 (has no hw encoder)
```

Comment: Is it working when you just open the device? Code: `AVBufferRef* hw_device_ref;int ret = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&hw_device_ref, AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_QSV, "auto", NULL, 0);if (ret < 0) printf("Error!");`

Comment: Yes, it works fine

Comment: What is `buffer_t`? Can you explain the following line: `auto ctx = (AVD3D11VADeviceContext *)((AVHWDeviceContext *)ctx_buf->data)->hwctx;`?  There are so many casts, it can't be correct... Can you explain the lock and unlock part? Is there any code sample you are using as reference?

Comment: this is the project I'm using as reference: https://github.com/caioavidal/Sunshine/blob/qsv/sunshine/video.cpp#L1799
I'm trying to encode d3d11 frames on qsv encoder

Comment: Is it the equivalent to `-init_hw_device qsv=hw_any,child_device_type=d3d11va` from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393446/qsv-encoder-error-when-running-in-different-main-display)? Are you getting the error with the main display connected to the iGPU?

Comment: No, this is related to d3d11 texture encoding using qsv. I'm trying to achieve it deriving qsv hwcontext from d3d11va hwcontext and then mapping the frames from d3d device to qsv device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to d3d11 device solved the issue:

```
ID3D10Multithread *pMultithread;

  status = device->QueryInterface(IID_ID3D10Multithread, (void **)&pMultithread);
  if(SUCCEEDED(status)) {
    pMultithread->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);
    Release(pMultithread);
  }
```