# QSV encoder error when running in different main display

Tags: ffmpeg

My Windows 10 (x64) computer has two HW accelerated video devices:

- an nVidia video card as the main display adapter (ID: 0)
- and intel iGPU used as extended display (ID: 1)

When running this command below it simply doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=qsv:hw_any -filter_hw_device qsv -i train_hw264.mp4 -an -vf "format=nv12,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=20" -c:v h264_qsv record.mp4 -y -loglevel verbose
```

returning this error:

```
[AVHWFramesContext @ 00000227dfaadb80] Error opening the internal VPP session.Surface upload/download will not be possible
```

If a switch the main display to intel IGPU everything works fine.

I also tried using OBS with my nvidia as main display and it seems to work fine.

Can anyone help me out on this?
Thank you

Comment: The "Surface" issue is somehow related to the video rendering configuration of the OS. In Windows 10, QSV supports system memory, DirectX 9 (D3D9) and DirectX 11 (D3D11) (surface applies "video memory" resource). The surfaces may be shared with OpenCL. It looks like a bug in the interface between Intel and Microsoft (or a bug in FFmpeg). Are you using any video filter except `format` or are you just re-encode the video?

Comment: According to [FFmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): **qsv** Use the Intel QuickSync Video acceleration for video transcoding... this option does not enable accelerated decoding... but accelerated transcoding, without copying the frames into the system memory. For it to work, both the decoder and the encoder must support QSV acceleration and **no filters must be used**.

Comment: I'm also using qsv scale. I noticed that when I don't use hw frames it works fine. I mean, if I remove the hwupload and replace and use -init_hw_device d3d11va=qsv:hw_any it works fine. Also tested on c++ application not allocating hw frames for qsv and it also works. So I think the problem lies on creating hwframes.

Comment: Running this for instance: "./ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw_any -filter_hw_device hw_any -f gdigrab -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -i desktop -an -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast record.mp4 -y -v verbose"
I'm getting: "Error opening the internal VPP session.Surface upload/download will not be possible"

Comment: Using Intel HD Graphics 530 (Core i7 Gen 6), I am getting an error `Unsupported pixel format: bgra`. I added `format=nv12`, and getting the same error `Surface upload/download will not be possible` using FFmpeg 4.4. Using FFmpeg 5.0, the command is working when display is connected. `ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw_any:hw,child_device_type=d3d11va -filter_hw_device hw_any -f gdigrab -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 60 -i desktop -an -vf "format=nv12,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast record.mp4 -y -v verbose"`

Comment: After executing the command once with FFmpeg 5, it started working with FFmpeg 4.4 (looks like some kind of initialization issue). When the monitor is connected to NVIDIA GPU, I am getting an error message `Error initializing an MFX session: -3.` `Device creation failed: -1313558101.` `Failed to set value 'qsv=hw_any:hw,child_device_type=d3d11va' for option 'init_hw_device': Unknown error occurred`

Comment: It should be `qsv=hw_any,child_device_type=d3d11va` (not `qsv=hw_any:hw,child_device_type=d3d11va`).

Comment: It is inconsistent - even with FFmpeg 5, now I am getting error: "Surface upload/download will not be possible"

Comment: Yes, it only works when I have my main display setting on windows set to igpu monitor. Note that I have both gpus connected to a display. Not sure if is a mfx or ffmpeg limitation

Comment: It could be Windows 10 limitation (Microsoft fault). Some kind of GPU rendering (or memory) capability may be limited to one GPU? In Windows 7, the QSV was not working at all without a monitor. The solution was to define a virtual monitor that is connected to the iGPU (I can't find a way to do it in Windows 10).

Comment: Yes,but I mean should this happen to me as I have a single display connected to each gpu? (igpu and nvidia gpu). This looks like mfx session is not recognizing igpu because windows has main display set to nvidia gpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working adding child_device to init_hw_device like:

```
-init_hw_device qsv=intel,child_device=1
```